# Any Good WordPress Themes Compatible With The BBPress Plugin?

Tags: themes, bbpress

Does anyone know of any good wordpress themes that are compatible with the bbpress *plugin*? I'm looking for something with a good layout, preferably a magazine/news type theme.

Thanks :)

Comment: there are a few out there but not many your best bet is a google search for bbpress themes with deep integration. You can always make a bbpress compatible theme though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be if you modify the bbpress theme a bit.Copy the entire folder "/bbpress/bbp-themes/bbp-twentyten" folder into your themes folder, rename it to something else, and modify your style.css to make it a custom child theme of whatever your current theme is.

Now you can modify as you you wish.

Another way :Copy all files of that folder inside ur theme.

In your theme's function.php add the following line.

> add_theme_support( 'bbpress' );

Now you have your theme compatible with ur own bbpress page structure which you can modify as you wish.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If your budget stretches, the Genesis theme works well with bbpress once you install the compatibility plugin.  There are a tonne of child themes for Genesis - you'll easily find a magazine / news type one that will suit.  You can see it running on my site (currently the Lifestyle theme): http://www.nxtab.co.uk/discussion/

Unfortunately Genesis is a premium theme but I figured it's worth the cash to get something that actually works and looks good.  Save yourself some time and get on with something productive!

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.google.com/search?q=bbpress+themes and http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/guangzhou and http://bbpress.org/documentation/themes/